# Why is my boolean of value 0 returning true?

Tags: .net, powershell, parameters, boolean, powershell-3.0

I've been working on some PowerShell scripts and found something a little odd.
I have a script that accepts 4 mandatory parameters: two strings and two Booleans.

`.\[scriptname] [string1] [string2] [bool1] [bool2]`

This works fine, and I've checked that they are all being passed correctly.

However, I've found something rather strange when PowerShell asks for parameters; it sets both booleans to true.

```
.\[scriptname] [string1] [string2]
please enter bool1: 0
please enter boo2: 0
```

It then runs the script as if bool1 and bool2 were set to true, and not to what I've set them to. I have true passing in all sorts of different things, and it always results in true.

I'm unsure as to why this is happening, and wanted to know if anyone has come across a cause or solution to this bizarre problem!

I've also found that the Task Scheduler has a similar issue. 
Set it up with

`powershell -file [scriptlocation] [string1] [string2] [bool1] [bool2]`

example:

> powershell -file "C:\script1.ps1" "c:\fileOne.txt" "c:\folder1" 0 0

Both booleans come through as strings.

Comment: Please post source that shows this behavior

Comment: Its not really to do with my source code, as all I'm doing is passing them in as mandatory parameters.
Its moot what happens with the rest of the script.

Comment: Hopefully you can see the benefit of posting your code now. It may not seem immediately relevant to do so, but it gives us crucial context to be able to reproduce your problem and help you sooner. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) by Jeffrey Snover offers some insight on the behavior of booleans in Powershell.  Below is an excerpt, where he creates a simple function "test" to return true or false depending on the input parameter:

```
PS> test "0"
TRUE
PS> test 0
FALSE
PS> test 1
TRUE
PS> test 0.0
FALSE
PS> test 0x0
FALSE
PS> test 0mb
FALSE
PS> test 0kb
FALSE
PS> test 0D
FALSE
PS> test 0.00000001
TRUE
```

> “0” is TRUE because it is a STRING and it has a length of 1.  0 is
>   FALSE because it is a number and that number is 0.  In PowerShell, any
>   number which evaluates to 0 is FALSE and every non-zero number is
>   TRUE.  The example shows you a floating point zero, a hexadecimal
>   zero, 0 megs, 0 kilos, 0 decimal, there are all sorts of zeros but to
>   PowerShell, they all evaluate to FALSE.

Without any sample code it is hard to say exactly what is happening, but what we can say is that your input isn't being identified as zero by Powershell.  Perhaps it is a string? This would be true if you used `Read-Host` to get user input.  Here's an example:

```
PS C:\> $test = Read-Host "Input"
Input: 0
PS C:\> $test.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

PS C:\> test $test
TRUE

PS C:\> $test = [Int32]$test
PS C:\> test $test
FALSE
```

You can check by using `GetType()` on the variable in question, and fixing it may be a simple matter of explicitly casting to the desired type.

The more I read your question -- unless I've misunderstood it -- this seems to address your problems.  Especially where you comment that you've been "passing in all sorts of different things" as any non-zero length string would evaluate to true in this context.

```
PS C:\> $anotherTest = "42"
PS C:\> test $anotherTest
TRUE
PS C:\> $anotherTest = [Int32]$anotherTest
PS C:\> test $anotherTest
TRUE
```

---

**Edit:** Alright, I've worked a bit more on the problem now that I have some idea what your environment is.  First, everything I told you above is true, so please don't disregard it.  The problem you're experiencing is that the boolean type conversion is handling the powershell mandatory prompt input in a way that isn't immediately obvious.

So some situation exists where this code snippet:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)][bool]$myBool
)
Write-Host $myBool
```

Will cause the following result when you use powershell's mandatory parameter prompt instead of submitting the variable on the command line:

```
PS C:\> .\script.ps1 
cmdlet script.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters: 
myBool: 0 
True
```

Let me re-iterate: In Powershell, **all strings that are not of a null length evaluate to true.** This includes "0", and this includes string literals. But what's the problem?  We've already explicitly declared our variable as a `bool`, so it should understand that I mean 0, right?

Wrong. A rather unfortunate situation is created where we're expecting a bool, or at least a string, when we set our input to the prompt.  We do indeed eventually get out bool, but remember what happens to non-null strings when we convert them to bools?  The type conversion to bool is being applied to the literal input you set at the prompt, which is not a numeric type.  Since the input is of a non-null length, the bool conversion evaluates to true.  You are essentially performing this operation:

```
PS C:\> [bool]$myBool = [bool]"0"
PS C:\> $myBool
True
```

The big problem with this is that since we've already converted our variable to a bool, the string has been consumed and we're just left with the value 1, or True. So your "0" literally turned into 1. We can't get the 0 back anymore.  What should we do?  I'll list a couple of options:

- Set your variable as an `[int]` type instead of a `[bool]`.  The bool conversion consumed the "0" string and turned it into a 1, so why not use a type that *won't* do that?  Powershell understands numerical 0s and 1s to be true and false, so you can use any numerical type.

Example with output:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(mandatory=$true)][int]$myBool
)
Write-Host $myBool

PS C:\> .\script1.ps1
cmdlet script1.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
myBool: 0
0
```

- If you are using the bools as logic switches, consider the `[switch]` parameter type instead.  Switches always evaluate to false unless you explicitly set them.  You shouldn't ever expose the prompt this way, so you won't encounter this problem. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Nice explanation on different types of input.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, this doesn't quite answer my question.
What I'm asking is why does it change from accepting 0 and 1 along the command line as true and false, yet when it asks for the commands it then decides they are true?

Comment: The difference between the command line and the cmdlet is that the command line is smart enough to inplicitly interpret your input -- the cmdlet, on the other hand, has a strict return type. I could comment further if I knew what cmdlet you were using, but it looks like Read-Host.  Check [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849945.aspx) on Read-Host, the output is System.String even if you put in a numerical value.  You'll need to explicitly "cast" that string to some numerical type, like an int, for it to understand that you mean 0 and not "0".

Comment: @Hazz22  
There is also the other possibility that instead of using Read-Host, you have defined a mandatory parameter and are simply letting it fall through to powershell's prompt... which ends up having a similar problem as Read-Host. You end up with an object of type `string` because you're no longer using powershell's interactive console. In either instance, just cast your variable as `[int]$value` or `[bool]$value`, and you'll be able to work with the input.

Comment: I see what you mean, but unfortunately all of the variables are explicitly typed. So PowerShell should know them as a bool. This is what makes so little sense!
I'll post some code a little later on to show you what i mean.

Comment: Sorry for not putting any code up yet.I've been rather busy. But your explanation was spot on! That's exactly the issue I'd encountered, and wondered if i was going progressively mad!
I've actually gone a slightly different way in my solution, and this is via strings. I've allowed the user to pass in "true", "false", "0" or "1", and added a conversion function to a module I'd created.

Thanks for this, and will mark it as solved!

Answer (score 0):

if your function is not accepting the parameters as boolean, that might explain why this is happening (Hyper Anthony explained it well).

So, does your script has param ([string]x1, [string[x2],[bool]y1,[bool]y2) type of declaration ? In that case y1 and y2 would be boolean, but if not may be getting treated as string with value 0, in which case it is treated like "0" which is not equal to 0

Comment: All of the mandatory parameters have been set explicitly, which makes this a little odd. I'll post some example code later, to show what i mean.