# Evaluating WMI output

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to evaluate output from some WMI commands.  All the examples I've seen do something like $objWMI.Version to get the actual setting but I can't seem to get that to work.

Example:
$test = "get-wmiobject -namespace root\webadministration -class directorybrowsesection | select Enabled | format-list"

I want to do something depending on if this returns true or false

I've tried things like:
if ($test -eq "False")
if ($test.Enabled -eq "False")
if ($test -match "False")

For reference running the WMI command itself returns:
Enabled : False

Running `Get-Member` outputs the following:

```
get-wmiobject -namespace root\webadministration -class directorybrowsesection | select Enabled 

TypeName: Selected.System.Management.ManagementObj 

Name MemberType Definition 
---- ---------- ---------- 
Equals Method bool Equals(System.Object ob 
GetHashCode Method int GetHashCode() 
GetType Method type GetType() 
ToString Method string ToString() 
Enabled NoteProperty System.Boolean Enabled=False –
```

Comment: Why are you expecting this to return a single boolean value?

Comment: running the WMI command itself returns: Enabled : False

I want to take that "Enabled : False" and depending on if it's false or true do something else.

Comment: Try piping your cmdlet to `| Get-Member` to get more information about the object type and properties you're dealing with.  Also, you can use $true and $false instead of "True" and "False".  You may be surprised to find that `[bool]"False"` outputs True because you aren't identifying false, but instead a string value of nonzero length.

Comment: Thanks for Get-Member, didn't know about that and it helped me understand some things.  I'm still having the same problem tho with using $test -eq $false.

The command is looking at a setting in IIS so I thought it was a string output which is why I did "false" before.

Comment: No problem. We may be able to help some more, try pasting the line with Get-Member and output into your post.  If it helps, you probably don't need `format-list` either and it may be complicating things.

Comment: I actually removed format-list from my script because I thought it might be causing problems but didn't fix it. Below is the output of: get-wmiobject -namespace root\webadministration -class directorybrowsesection | select Enabled  
 TypeName: Selected.System.Management.ManagementObj Name MemberType Definition ---- ---------- ---------- Equals Method bool Equals(System.Object ob GetHashCode Method int GetHashCode() GetType Method type GetType() ToString Method string ToString() Enabled NoteProperty System.Boolean Enabled=False

Comment: I'm new here so forgive my formatting, I'm trying to see how to fix that.

Comment: No worries, I edited it into the post body for you.  Try `$test.Enabled` again, this time with `$test.Enabled -eq $false`.

Comment: Tried that, still nothing :( Here is the exact code, maybe I'm missing something. 
    $V_25994 = "get-wmiobject -namespace root\webadministration -class directorybrowsesection | select Enabled"
    if ($V_25994.Enabled -eq $false)
    {
    echo "Group ID: V-25994`r`nCompliant: True"
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Group ID: V-25994`r`nCompliant: False"
    
    }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do have a bool to work with, try this instead:

```
if ($myBool -eq $false)
{
  # Do Stuff
}
```

The string "False" is not actually false.  In fact, when converting it directly to a bool, it returns true because a "true" string value in .NET is defined as a non-zero length string:

```
PS C:\> [bool]"False"
True
PS C:\> [bool]""
False
```

Here's a [previous answer to a related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516048/why-is-my-boolean-of-value-0-returning-true/18516573#18516573), and some extended elaboration on bools in powershell.

Comment: Tried that and it still isn't working $test -eq $false. The command is looking at a setting in IIS so I thought it was a string output which is why I did "false" before.

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting the objects to an array and evaluating them there:

```
$test = (get-wmiobject -namespace root\webadministration -class directorybrowsesection | select enabled, property1, property2, etc)

foreach ($item in $test)
    if ($item.enabled -eq $false)
    {
        # do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        # do something different
    }
```