# PowerShell Boolean accepts all numbers

Tags: powershell, boolean

I think I'm missing something obvious here. In my understanding a `Boolean` can only be `0`, `$False`, `1` or `$True`. But when I try other integers, they are also accepted as `$True`.

When using other integers then `0` or `1` the function should throw an error saying that it's not a `Boolean`. Or should this be solved by adding error handling with `ValidateSet` for these 4 different input options?

**Example:**

```
Function Test-Bar {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
        [Bool]$Var
    )
    Write-Host "Yes, you entered a valid boolean: $Var" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}

[INT]$Number = '0'
Test-Bar -Var $Number

[INT]$Number = '1'
Test-Bar -Var $Number

[INT]$Number = '10'
Test-Bar -Var $Number # Incorrect, ten is not a boolean

[INT]$Number = '22'
Test-Bar -Var $Number # Incorrect, twenty two is not a boolean
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: FYI simply typing this `[bool]10` replicated this behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up Matt. But I really want my function to only accept `$True`, `$False`, `0` or `1` and nothing else. I thought this was possible with the `Boolean` type..

Comment: Oh I understand. I was just trying to point out your function could be simplified for the purpose of testing. Doesnt really help but [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2286.understanding-booleans-in-powershell.aspx) says "And (usually) any non-zero integer evaluates as $true"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18516573/3829407 links to a blog post that says: In PowerShell, any number which evaluates to 0 is FALSE and every non-zero number is TRUE. You need to account for this differently it seems. LIke `ValidateSet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the `[bool]` type implicitly casts anything that's not `$null`, `$false`, `0` or an empty string as `$true`

```powershell
> [bool]$true
True
> [bool]'foo'
True
> [bool]$false
False
> [bool]''
False
> [bool]$null
False
```

I'd have thought that in your case, using a `SwitchParameter` in your `cmdletbinding` would be suitable:

```powershell
Function Test-Bar {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0)]
        [Switch]$Var
    )
    Write-Host "Yes, you entered a valid boolean: $Var" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

And call like:

```powershell
> Test-Bar -var
Yes, you entered a valid boolean: True
> Test-Bar -var:$false
Yes, you entered a valid boolean: False
```

You may also want to look at the answers [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484682/safely-converting-string-to-bool-in-powershell) which discuss ways to test/convert to boolean if you really have to.

Comment: This does not work given the constraints of the OP. `Test-Bar 0` and `Test-Bar 1` fail.

Comment: @Matt I realise that, this is intended as an alternative approach. The `switch` parameter, as far as I can tell, exists for precisely this scenario

Comment: After checking your suggestion and Matt's documentation, it seems indeed adviced to just use the `Switch` parameter. I only need to figure out to transform `0` to `$False` and `1` to `$True` before I fill the splatting hash table to feed the function. Thank you guys, I was apparently wrong about `Booleans`.